# LatLonBox to CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: ios, mkmapview, kml

I try to convert LatLonBox coordinate to CLLocationCoordinate2D. But I think somewhere is a mistake because die Image doesn't fit..

```
 <LatLonBox>
  <north>2.254403</north>
  <south>-55.256903</south>
  <east>161.994477</east>
  <west>98.003023</west>
  <rotation>0</rotation>
</LatLonBox>
```

Here my function to convert the LatLonBox coordinates.

** --- MapOverlay : NSObject --- **

```
-(id)initWithNorth:(double)north south:(double)south west:(double)west east:(double)east imageStr:(NSString*)imageStr{

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        imageString = imageStr;

        CLLocationCoordinate2D lowerLeftCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(south, west); // south, west
        CLLocationCoordinate2D upperRightCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(north, east); //north,east


        baseCoordinate = lowerLeftCoordinate;

        MKMapPoint lowerLeft = MKMapPointForCoordinate(lowerLeftCoordinate);
        MKMapPoint upperRight = MKMapPointForCoordinate(upperRightCoordinate);

        mapRect = MKMapRectMake(lowerLeft.x, upperRight.y, upperRight.x - lowerLeft.x, lowerLeft.y - upperRight.y);
    }

    return self;
}
```

** --- MapOverlayView : MKOverlayView --- **

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{

    CGImageRef imageReference = image.CGImage;

    //Loading and setting the image
    MKMapRect theMapRect    =  [self.overlay boundingMapRect];
    CGRect theRect           = [self rectForMapRect:theMapRect];


    // We need to flip and reposition the image here
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, -theRect.size.height);

    //drawing the image to the context
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, theRect, imageReference);

}
```

** --- My Map --- **

```
//Adding the overlay to the map
MapOverlay * mapOverlay = [[MapOverlay alloc] initWithNorth:2.254403
                                                      south:-55.256903
                                                       west:161.994477
                                                       east:98.003023
                                                   imageStr:@"EarthquakeHazard.png"];
[self addOverlay:mapOverlay];
```

The thing is, if I change the north value. (-2.2544..) The image move down. Then it should not move up to??

---

**Well, the functionality works fine and correct. My .kml file had wrong values...**

**Thanks for your help!!!**

Comment: What do you mean by "image doesn't fit" exactly?  Where and how are you showing an image?  How does it appear?  What kind of class is this code in?  Also remember that map view usually does not show the _exact_ map rect that you request (it adjusts it based on zoom level and proportions of the map view frame).

Comment: I try to add an Overlayer image to the MKMapView. The image and the coordinates are coming from a .kml file. Thats works fine with the exception that the image on the wrong y pos is...

Comment: It might help if you also show the code that adds the image overlay.

Comment: Done! Maybe do you understand my problem now?

Comment: A negative latitude value means "below the Equator".  Where you call initWithNorth, I think you have the east and west parameters backwards: west should be 98.xxx and east should be 161.xxx.

Answer (score 0):

```
mapRect = MKMapRectMake(lowerLeft.x, upperRight.y, upperRight.x - lowerLeft.x, lowerLeft.y - upperRight.y);
```

should probably be

```
mapRect = MKMapRectMake(lowerLeft.x, upperRight.y, upperRight.x - lowerLeft.x, upperRight.y - lowerLeft.y);
```

Comment: unfortunately not. after your suggestion is the layer instead of Australia in Asia. Thanks anyway!